# Invoking multi-line (G)AWK program in one line

Tags: linux, shell, awk

I'm wondering if it's possible to run a multi-line (G)AWK program through the shell where I can't have tabs or newlines.

It seems to crop up as an issue when I have variable assignments. For instance:

```
awk '{one=$1 two=$2}'
```

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to add semicolons between instructions, as you state.

However, return is also an option in most shells, just hit return before closing the awk instruction:

```
$ awk '{one=$1
> two=$2}' test.txt
```

note that `>` is added by the shell. This is also documented in the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Other-Command_002dLine-Arguments).

Answer (score -1):

Looks like simply adding the stock-standard semi-colon will allow for this:

```
awk '{one=$1;two=$2}'
```